# AWS SQS Consumer not consuming messages

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using the `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` in my Spring Boot application and `@sqslistener` to consume SQS messages. my consumer weirdly stops getting messages out of nowhere and the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` gradually increases triggering a CloudWatch alarm. I could see no error logs that are generated before it stops getting any more messages. Am I missing something?

```
    @SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue.url.indexSavedSetQueue}",
        deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void listenIndexSavedSetEvent(@NonNull String message) throws IOException {
        log.info("Index saved set event received, message: {}", message);

        IndexSavedSetPayloadDto indexSavedSetPayloadDto = objectMapper
            .readValue(message, IndexSavedSetPayloadDto.class);

        String setName = indexSavedSetPayloadDto.getSetName();
        indexerService.indexSet(setName);
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve it?